# Can you give some example or 2D Objects that we experience in our daily life?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

We see 3D Objects in our daily life like car, house etc. But we cannot see 2D objects. Can you give some example of **2D objects that we experience in our daily life**?
Don't give example of 2D Polygons/patterns on paper or screens of mobile phone/laptop or TV.

Comment: Do surfaces make the list?

Comment: How about shadows on (flat) surfaces?

Comment: Yes yes, shadows are perfect example of 2D objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Everything* in our eality is three dimensional - it extends in all three spatial dimensions (okay, there may be some debate as to whether an individual fundamental particle has any spatial extent, but certainly anything at or above the atomic level is three dimensional). If you include time then you could say that everything is four-dimensional because everything has a duration as well.

Two dimensional objects or spaces - such as an ideal triangle, a two-dimensional plane, or the surface of a sphere - are mathematical abstractions. Sometimes these mathematical abstractions are useful as an *approximate* model of some aspect of reality. For example, a position on the surface the Earth can be modelled by longitude and latitude, which ignores its altitude/elevation because this is usually small compared to the radius of the Earth. However, once we go into orbit or talk about a position *inside* the Earth, this simplified two dimensional model breaks down.

Similarly, you can model a position on a laptop screen or on a piece of paper or on a wall using two co-ordinates because these surface are approximately flat at scales of, say, 1mm or greater. But once you go down to the molecular level then they are far from flat, and once again the two-dimensional model breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Your position on planet Earth is essentially 2D. Whenever something is defined by 2 numbers, it may imply that it is bound to a 2D space.

A [sheet of graphene](https://www.materialstoday.com/carbon/news/graphene-is-3d-as-well-as-2d/) is essentially 2D. Very cool!